# Why would Laravel 5.6 / Eloquent disagree with it's own database connection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

My app is exhibiting this strange behavior in a production environment, and no where else (happens both in the actual interface and in tinker):

```
>>> $db = DB::connection();
=> Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection {#832}
>>> \App\User::resolveConnection()->select('select * from users');
=> [
     {#838
       +"id": 2,
       +"deleted_at": "2018-04-10 20:47:07",
       ...perfectly normal data
     },
     {#848
       +"id": 3,
       +"deleted_at": "2018-04-10 20:47:07",
       ...perfectly normal data
     },
   ]
>>> \App\User::resolveConnection()->select('select * from users');
=> [
     {#846
       +"id": 2,
       ...perfectly normal data
     },
     {#839
       +"id": 3,
       ...perfectly normal data
     },
   ]
>>> \App\User::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#861
     all: [],
   }
```

The User class is fairly plain:

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Laravel\Cashier\Billable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use Billable;
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'status'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Organization::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Guessing, but are all of your users soft deleted? `Eloquent` will automatically apply the relevant soft delete where clause, whereas the `DB` won't.

Comment: @fubar you are exactly right, answer so I can mark you up

Comment: Doh. Quick, delete the question before anyone else sees ;)

Comment: nah, maybe I'll keep someone else from stepping in it

Comment: You should add the answer @fubar ... this adds to the knowledge base...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is that you're using soft deletes on your `User` model. Therefore, are all of your users soft deleted?

Eloquent will automatically apply the relevant soft delete query scope to filter models that have been deleted, whereas a standard DB query will not.

The equivalent DB query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
```